# Best way to pay for airline tickets?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, payment

I know it's a bit of a strange question, but here goes...

**Background**: I don't travel by plane very often, and when I have it's always been someone else who actually purchased the tickets. I am trying to book a trip to Hawaii from Colorado, the total for the booking, including plane tickets for 2 and 1 hotel room, totals at just over $2000 (CheapTickets.com).

The issue comes when I try to make payment. I bank with Wells Fargo, and apparently the maximum daily purchase amount is $1500 with my debit card. So... how does one pay for a booking online? Is this just Wells Fargo being difficult, or is there a better way to pay for this?

P.S. Suggestions on how to find a better deal (if possible) are also welcome.

Edit: Some clarification, this is a Debit card with a balance comfortably higher than the purchase amount, so credit limits aren't an issue. Apparently $1500 is the highest Wells Fargo allows for daily purchase limits for a debit card.

Comment: Call your bank and ask them to raise the limit?

Comment: You might get better answers at [Money.SE].

Comment: _One has a credit card with a higher limit_. Seriously, it is rare to not have a credit card, and that's by far the easiest way. If you don't want one: I had that issue decades ago when moving newly to the US, and I paid a friend cash and he booked with his credit card.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Daily transaction limits are put in place by your card issuer to protect against fraud and credit default. Depending on your credit status, if you call your card provider you should be able to get the limit increased either permanently or as a one-off. https://www08.wellsfargomedia.com/assets/pdf/personal/debit-card/terms-and-conditions.pdf